# Does couchDB not need a backend scripting language ?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I was just learning how couchDb works and basically i was reading this article **[HERE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-couchdb/)**. Noticel how the below code is used to save data to the crouchDB database:

```
$('input#updateId').click(function(e) {

   if ($('#idId').val().length == 0) {
       return;
   }

   var aTask = {
       _id: $('#idId').val(),
       _rev: $('#revId').val(),
       amount: $('#amountId').val(),
       name:$('#nameId').val()
   }
   db.saveDoc(aTask, { success: function(resp) {
       refreshItems();
   }});
});
```

This function saves the data to the couchDB database. My question is does couchDB not require a scripting backend language ? if so Why ?

Comment: If you put your application logic all in the front-end javascript, then no it doesn't need server-side application code.

Comment: @user1389596 thanks , i guess that answers my question .